# str(None) in python condition checks

Tags: python

Say I have a variable in python `a`

if `a` is `None`, then is `str(None)` going to return `None` or something else?

I ran this in an intepreter an did something like:

```
a = str(None)
print(a is None)
```

And it printed `False`, why is that?

Comment: `str(None) == 'None'` will return true, if this helps you understand

Comment: `a` is a 4 character string spelling out the word None (not the python `None`). It may help to visualize it by `print(list(a))` which separates the characters into a list `['N', 'o', 'n', 'e']`.

Comment: _f a is None, then is str(None) going to return None or something else?_ Why not just look at the result of `str(None)` directly?

Comment: `print(str(None))` will tell you quite quickly what the return value looks like.  Don't ask us when you can make the computer give you the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, `str` will **always** return a string. In this case, `str(None)` is the string `"None"`. `"None"` is not equal to `None` since one is a string and the other is the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

Converting it to a string is changing it to the word "None". Try the below.

```py
a = str(None)
print(type(a))
print(type(None))
print('None' == None)
```

This will output the below.

```py
<class 'str'>
<class 'NoneType'>
False
```

A string and a NoneType are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `is` is an identity operator, meaning that it returns `True` if both variables are the same object. Objects referencing `None` will always have the same identity, however, `str(None)` and `None` will not have the same identity, therefore your print statement returns `False`.

The `is` operator has nothing to do with whether something is equal in value, you have to use `==` operator for that. See examples below.

```
a = str(None)

>>>print(a == None)
False
>>> print(a is None)
False
>>> print(a is str(None))
False
>>> print(a == str(None))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

With regard to your first question (you should have only one per post, by the way), you can figure this out by running it yourself.

With regard to your second question, you are printing the value of the expression `a is None`.  `a` is either `None` or it isn't.  Either way, you'll get a Boolean value.  In this case, `a` isn't `None` but rather a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to print out the result of a, and then you know why the result is `False`.

```py
a = str(None)
print(type(a))
print(a is None)
```